# Extracción números desde un string MySQL

Tags: mysql, time

Tengo una columna en una base de datos SQL donde se contabiliza la duración de un evento. El formato puede variar entre:

1. '12 days 15 hours 30 minutes'
2. '4 days 9 hours 8 minutes'
3. '1 day 1 hour 1 minute'
4. '10 days 1 hour 1 minute'
5. '15 hours 30 minutes'
6. '1 hour 30 minutes'
7. '1 hour 1 minute'

Etc...

¿Cómo puedo obtener la suma en horas de cualquiera de esas opciones? Es decir, si el texto dice '4 days 9 hours 8 minutes' el resultado debería ser: 4*(24)+9*(1)+8/(60) = 105.13

Con los datos anteriores el resultado sería:

1. 303.50
2. 105.13
3. 25.02
4. 241.02
5. 15.50
6. 1.50
7. 1.02

Intenté combinar LOCATE y SUBSTRING para aislar primero los números y aplicar las multiplicaciones correspondientes. También intenté utilizar STR_TO_DATE, pero en ambos casos siempre llego a un punto en el que la función se hace insuficiente.

Comment: Te recomendaría que, si está a tu alcance, normalices la situación, convirtiendo los datos de la columna a un formato `TIME` o `TIMESTAMP`, determinando lo que hay escrito en cada cadena. De todos modos tendrás que hacerlo para este caso puntual y en cualquier otro momento que necesites hacer cálculos con esos datos guardados así. El error fue precisamente decidir guardarlos así en lugar de guardarlos de una forma adecuada y lista para hacer cualquier cálculo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sale en 3 rondas (sub-consultas):

1. **Estandarizar** eliminando plural, espacios y abreviando palabras.
   Uso la función `replace()` anidada.
2. **Extraer valores** con base en la posición de las abreviaciones.
   La posición es almacenada en variables de usuario. La extracción con la función `substr()`.
3. **Cálculo** y redondeo de horas

```
SELECT str
     -- , std, d, h, m
     , round(24*d+h+m/60,2) horas 
  FROM ( SELECT str
              , std
              , @d:= instr( std, 'd' ) dpos
              , @h:= instr( std, 'h' ) hpos
              , @m:= instr( std, 'm' ) mpos
              , substr( std, 1, @d-1 ) d
              , substr( std, @d+1, @h-@d-1 ) h
              , substr( std, if(@h<>0,@h,@d)+1, @m-if(@h<>0,@h,@d)-1 ) m
           FROM ( SELECT str
                       , replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( str
                                                                    , ' ', ''
                                                                    )
                                                           , 's', '' 
                                                           )
                                                  , 'minute' , 'm'
                                                  )
                                         , 'hour', 'h'
                                         )
                                , 'day' ,'d'
                                ) std
                    FROM ( SELECT '12 days 15 hours 30 minutes' str
                           UNION
                           SELECT '4 days 9 hours 8 minutes'
                           UNION 
                           SELECT '1 day 1 hour 1 minute'
                           UNION
                           SELECT '10 days 1 hour 1 minute'
                           UNION
                           SELECT '15 hours 30 minutes'
                           UNION
                           SELECT '1 hour 30 minutes'
                           UNION
                           SELECT '1 hour 1 minute'
                         ) t1
                ) t2
        )t3;
```